# sc.wholeTextFiles + toDebugString takes long time even before action is performed

Tags: apache-spark

Below is a simple code segment.

inputForCust is 14762 files totalling 57M only with an average file size as 0.5K. The files are loaded from local filesystem mounted through NFS.

```
val inputCustFiles = sc.wholeTextFiles(inputForCust, jobArgs.minPartitions)
println("This prints immediately")
inputCustFiles.toDebugString
println("This prints after 20 mins")
inputCustFiles.count
println("This prints after 10 mins")
```

Note: We were having some complex transformations after the wholeTextFile and the time was taken in reduceByKey!!! I have simplified the code to reproduce the problem only.

**My question is, Why inputCustFiles.toDebugString is taking so much time?**

If, inputCustFiles.count takes time, I can be assured that it is going to take advantage of the cluster processing power. But inputCustFiles.toDebugString is blocking the driver!!!

In the duration of 20 min, I see no activity in the spark UI.

If I enable trace level logging, I see below lines

```
[error] [17/03/17 23:23:27] [DEBUG] BlockManager: Getting local block broadcast_1
[error] [17/03/17 23:23:27] [DEBUG] BlockManager: Level for block broadcast_1 is StorageLevel(true, true, false, true, 1)
[error] [17/03/17 23:23:27] [DEBUG] BlockManager: Getting block broadcast_1 from memory
[error] [17/03/17 23:23:43] [TRACE] HeartbeatReceiver: Checking for hosts with no recent heartbeats in HeartbeatReceiver.
[error] [17/03/17 23:24:43] [TRACE] HeartbeatReceiver: Checking for hosts with no recent heartbeats in HeartbeatReceiver.
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

**Any idea, if I am doing anything wrong or is this a limitation/bug/design of spark?**

Note:

- We are using 1.6.2.
- The time takes for toDebugString increases if the number of input file changes!!!

Below is the stack trace at the time driver is blocked

```
java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
java.io.BufferedReader.read1(BufferedReader.java:212)
java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:286)
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.parseExecResult(Shell.java:602)
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:446)
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:379)
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:589)
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:678)
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:661)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.execCommand(FileUtil.java:1097)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$RawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.java:567)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$RawLocalFileStatus.getPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:542)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocatedFileStatus.<init>(LocatedFileStatus.java:42)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.next(FileSystem.java:1815)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.next(FileSystem.java:1797)
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:267)
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileInputFormat.getSplits(CombineFileInputFormat.java:217)
org.apache.spark.rdd.WholeTextFileRDD.getPartitions(WholeTextFileRDD.scala:49)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.firstDebugString$1(RDD.scala:1747)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.toDebugString(RDD.scala:1781)
oculus.storeonce.spark.Test$.main(Test.scala:11)
oculus.storeonce.spark.Test.main(Test.scala)
```

Comment: Something strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, spark driver goes through the file system and  gets a great deal of meta data so that it can create the right number of partition of proper size. As file systems (even HDFS) are not efficient at handling small files, scanning the file system for this metadata is causing the delay!!!

Why rdd.reduceByKey... or rdd.toDebugString are invoking the operation and not sc.wholeTextFiles/textFiles or rdd.map are not is still a question!!!

The solution/workaround is to host the data in something like kafka/cassandra or merging the content of many files to single file.